# div tag in the div tag doesn't appear well in the browser

Tags: html, css

this is my html code

```
                <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; height: 809px; width : 50%; float: left; font-size: medium; text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
                    Job member<br />
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        PageSize="20" Width="50%">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CheckBoxField>
                            <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                            </asp:CheckBoxField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="User" DataField="user_id" />
                            <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="View" Text="Button" />
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle Height="20px" />
                        <RowStyle Width="20px" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; height: 809px; width : 50%">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        PageSize="20" Width="50%">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CheckBoxField>
                            <ItemStyle Width="10px" />
                            </asp:CheckBoxField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="User" DataField="user_id" />
                            <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="View" Text="Button" />
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle Height="20px" />
                        <RowStyle Width="20px" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                </div>
```

i create 2 div tag within the div tag, and i set the width into 50% so the div tag can appear nicely in the browser, when i deploy to the browser, the appearance is totally loss... i have consider the border thickness issue, the second div tag might pull down because there is some width on the border, so i changed the width into 47% before, in the end the result is still same, may i ask if my way to create this kind of div tag is it correct?

this is how my visual developer looks like
[image]

this is how my browser looks like
[image]

please help

Comment: You should consider using bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/. Otherwise consider using flexbox for something like this. Also stay away from inline code, it's all got to be in the css!

Comment: also the code above is incomplete so I couldn't pen/fiddle with it. Could you create a pen on codepen.io ?

Comment: Here you go

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbrKMz.html